# vim: detect underlying file change when entering insert mode

Tags: vim

Here's a sequence of events:

1. Open a file in `vim`, make some edits, save it, and stay in normal mode;
2. The file gets changed by an external process, say `git`;
3. Go back to `vim`, enter insert mode (at this point file has been changed, but `vim` sees a stale version);
4. Make some edits to the stale version, go back to normal mode;
5. Save the file in `vim`.

When I do things like above, what typically happens is that `vim` warns me at step 5:

```
WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!!
Do you really want to write to it (y/n)?
```

This is rather inconvenient, because I already made some "valuable" edits. How can I ask `vim` to do the check at step 3, that is, before entering insert mode, check if the buffer is outdated and offer to reload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your ~/.vimrc:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * checktime
```

I.e., on entering Insert mode for any file (`*`) execute [checktime](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:checktime).